# How to set QTabWidget's background transparent using stylesheets

Tags: qt, background, transparent, qtstylesheets

I set a picture as background in the mainframe and add two widgets on it: a `QTableWidget` and a `QTabWidget`.

I have set the background of `tablewidget` to be transparent by `stylesheet`
in vs2013. The table's background shows the picture I set, but the `horizontalheader` section is still white:

```cpp
TaskInfWidget_->setStyleSheet("QTableWidget{background:transparent;}\
                           QTableWidget::item{border-top:1px solid grey;border-bottom:none;border-right:none;border-left:none;}\
                           QHeaderView::section{background:transparent;color:black; font-family:宋体;font-size:15px;font-weight:200;\
                                                    border:none;}");
```

But when I add a `tablewidget` in a `tabwidget` and set the `stylesheet` of the `tabwidget`, it doesn't work:

```cpp
QTabWidget *tab_widget=new QTabWidget;
QTableWidget *table = new QTableWidget(10, 1);
tab_widget->addtab(table,"hahaha");

tab_widget>setStyleSheet("QTabWidget::pane{background:transparent}\
            QTabBar::tab{background-color:transparent;height:30px;}\
            QTabBar::tab:selected{background-color:rgb(55,112,183)}\
            QTabBar::tab:hover{color:rgb(235,97,0);}");
table->setStyleSheet("QTableWidget{background:transparent;\
                         border:3px solid rgb(30,77,135);\
                         selection-background-color:rgb(30,77,135);}");
```

I have set `QTabWidget::pane{background:transparent}` and `QTableWidget{background:transparent}`, but the background of the `tablewidget` is still white, not the picture of the mainframe.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two minimal stylesheets to demonstrate only what is necessary to achieve background transparency.

For the header view item, apply this stylesheet on a QTableWidget:

```css
QHeaderView
{
    background: transparent;
}
QHeaderView::section
{
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
}
```

For a QTableWidget inside a QTabWidget, apply this stylesheet on a QTabWidget:

```css
QTabWidget::pane { 
    border: 1px solid white;
    /*or*/
    border: none;
}

QTabBar::tab {
    border: 1px solid white;
    /*or*/
    border: none;
}
```

And this stylesheet on the QTableWidget:

```css
QTableWidget
{
    background: transparent;
}

QHeaderView
{
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid white;
    /*or just remove the border, but it needs to be done explicitly*/
    border: none;
}

QHeaderView::section
{
    background:transparent;
    border: 1px solid white;
    /*or just remove the border, but it needs to be done explicitly*/
    border: none;
}
```

You could build up on these, and go one step back if you lose the transparency.

If for some reason this does make the background transparent, check if the parent widget's stylesheet is causing a conflict, especially `background` and `border`.

**Note:** this was tested using Fusion style, it might not work on other styles.